# Clear Firefox cache for every profile (Batch)

Tags: batch-file, firefox

This script clears the Firefox cache for the first profile in the directory. How do you do the same thing to every profile found if there are more than one? As you can see, I don't want to delete the folders named cache2, doomed, and entries. I just want to wipe their content.

```
CD /D %LOCALAPPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\**.default\cache2
FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%I IN ('DIR /B') DO IF NOT "%%I"=="doomed" IF NOT "%%I"=="entries" (RMDIR "%%I" /S /Q || DEL "%%I" /S /Q)
CD /D %LOCALAPPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\**.default\cache2\doomed
FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%I IN ('DIR /B') DO (RMDIR "%%I" /S /Q || DEL "%%I" /S /Q)
CD /D %LOCALAPPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\**.default\cache2\entries
FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%I IN ('DIR /B') DO (RMDIR "%%I" /S /Q || DEL "%%I" /S /Q)
```

Comment: If you do not want to delete directories, why are you using the command `rm` then?

Comment: @aschipfl because he wants to delete their **sub**folders.